# C# Memory Cache without memory-based evacuation

Tags: c#

I'm after an in-memory store which evacuates keys based on time/ttl, but which never evacuates anything based on some memory limit.

I currently have an object which is pretty much a wrapper around `ConcurrentDictionary` with a "vacuum" method which must be called periodically. This works fine, but I can't help feeling like there's something in .Net which does this for me? Is there something like MemoryCache without the memory-size-based evacuation?

Comment: What would "evacuation" mean in this context? Removal from cache? So a simple explanation would be something like, you want the cache to be filled until you get an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: @LousyCoder Yes - removal from cache. I am limiting what's stored (and scaling up as approaching that limit) outside of the cache. During scale-up it's OK to bounce against that limit. But you're implying that there's an upper bound regardless of what I do and that configuring a high upper bound is a better thing for me to concentrate on, since an OutOfMemoryException is the other eventuality. Which is a perfectly valid answer, it just needed to be framed as such! Cheers though, it jogged a thought process for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .NET's `MemoryCache` class, set an arbitrarily-high memory limit, like so (this example sets the limit to 75% of available memory; set the percentage you find viable):

```
var maxCache = new MemoryCache("MaxCache", new NameValueCollection {{"PhysicalMemoryLimit", "75" }});
```

and then use the `CacheItemPolicy` class to specify a sliding expiration.

For instance, to set a 10-minute sliding expiration, use:

```
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
```

Comment: Of course, that's so obvious now... :) I was trying to avoid coming up with a meaningful number for the cache (I need to limit on "number of things", not "amount of memory" - which I'll need to determine based on memory usage ofc). I also didn't realise you can specify a percentage like that. Thanks!